# Having an issue while uploading an image with multistep form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, image-processing

Getting an error while uploading an image with multistep form
TypeError (can't dump File):

I think I am receiving this error because of following line in controller

session[:admission_params].deep_merge!(params[:admission]) if params[:admission]

Just want to add

1. Multistep form is working fine, thanks http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms?view=asciicast
2. I have tried image uploading with single step form with Carrierwave, which is also working fine, thanks http://blog.assimov.net/post/4306595758/multi-file-upload-with-uploadify-and-carrierwave-on
3. Using rails 3.0.10, ruby 1.9.2 , carrierwave (0.5.7)

Comment: A solution is proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876714/multi-step-form-in-rails-3-with-paperclip-attachments

Comment: Thanks for giving me the direction.

Answer (score 2):

I was using multi-step form as well, and I stumbled upon the same problem. Once in your controller (after CarrierWave did his job), I found out that `params[:file]` is actually an object of type `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`, and the content of its `tempfile` variable is important.

Here is what allowed me to get rid of that `TypeError (can't dump file)` error:

```
 params[:file].tempfile = nil
```

My environment:

- rails-3.1.3
- carrierwave-0.5.8
- ruby 1.9.3